# iOS Firebase/APNS push notification sound according to local time or timezone

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to send iOS push notifications for an app that is used worldwide. Different users are in different time zones.

**Is there a way to specify ,that when delivered at worktime local time Mon-Fri (8:00 - 17:00) it will have sound, but any other it will be without sound.** I do not want to disturb the user at night.

This question is mostly about the **worst** situation **when my app isn't       running/backgrounded/suspended (for example after reboot) and/or offline**
.My app uses background fetch, but that doesn't guarantee that it will be running at the delivery time of the push notification.

The problem is i do not know in advance when the push notification will be delivered. If i knew i would specify the `sound` key in the `JSON`.
The user could be offline when the push notification is sent.

For example, i send the push notification at night without sound, but the user enables internet connection at day and receives the notification without sound (because it was sent in the night)

Scheduling the sending time at the server won't solve this, because we cannot control the delivery time.

**If it is possible using directly APNS without Firebase then that would also solve my problem.**

Thank you very much.

**Clarification:**

When my app is running i have enough control to decide according to local time if the sound should be played. The question is aimed at the other case when my app isn't running/backgrounded/suspended.

I am using silent data notifications (`JSON` key `data` with `content-available=1`) to deliver all neccessary info, but when my app is not running there is only one way to send a notification that will be shown - that is a `Display notification` (`JSON` key `notification`)

Comment: You're really complicating things too much. Most notifications are received within seconds of them being sent. The only big exception is people off a long flight. In most cases people will have appropriate settings on their device anyway, but if you know the user's time zone, you can adjust based on that when you send, you'll probably be right 99% of the time.

Comment: Note that if you really want to control this, there's an alternative: send a silent notification to your app, which will then use a local notification based on the local time. Note however that the probability of losing a notification or of significant delays is higher in this case.

Comment: I am already using silent notifications , but in the case after reboot - they won't start my app. If they would ,that would solve my problem, but i googled that it isn't possible before the user starts my app or background fetch starts my app